# How to show/hide layer by name in GIMP?

Tags: plugins, adobe-photoshop, gimp, psd

I received a pack of `.psd` files from a graphic designer that I need to use in the desktop app I'm developing.

I managed to open those files in `GIMP` (I work on `Ubuntu`) The problem is that there are too many layers in there and it is very hard to navigate through them to get to the layer I'm interested in.

Is there way in `GIMP` (or maybe plugin?) to show/hide layer by name and/or search for layer with specific name?

Answer (score -1):

Try [GIMP PLUGIN REGISTRY](http://registry.gimp.org/taxonomy/term/747)

Comment: and it has become invalid as of now. The link died